Increase payload in Express.js
This code sends "1" or "2" value as a cookie after pressing submit button:
<form action="/setorder" method="post" class="horizontal">
       <% if (req.cookies.doneAtLast == '1') { %>    
    <input type="hidden" name="done_at_last" value="0">
    <input type="submit" value="Do not sort">
        <% } else {%>
    <input type="hidden" name="done_at_last" value="1">
    <input type="submit" value="Sort">
       <% } %>    
</form>

However, I get 413 error.
req.cookies.doneAtLast is "{ doneAtLast: '1' }" right now.
I tried to increase pyload size :
import { Router, urlencoded, static as staticMiddleware } from 'express';
import methodOverride from 'method-override';
import { mainPage, detailedPage, addPage, add, setDone, remove, setOrder } from "./controllers/todos.js";
import { requestToContext, handleErrors } from './middleware.js';
import { mainErrorHandler, error500Handler } from './error-handlers.js';
import { todoV } from './validators.js';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
    
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
     
    // Route with increased JSON payload limit (50mb)
    app.post('/increased', express.json({ limit: '50mb' }), (req, res) => {
        res.send('Increased JSON payload limit');
      });
    
    const router = require(app).Router();
    
    ...
    router.post('/setorder', setOrder);

But it did not help.
Node.js v20.18.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

setOrder controller looks like this:
 export function setOrder(req, res){
  res.cookie('doneAtLast', req.body.done_at_last);
  res.redirect('/');
 } 

I am confused, because I am sending 0 or 1 to the cookies, but express marks it as 413 error.
